# How to get ecs metadata json response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have my ecs task running on fargate launch type version 1.4.0 and it is working properly it is using private ECR respository to get the app image. I want to get it's metadata. It has only private IP and i know this link [ecs fargate metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html) but i am not able to find anywhere this variable `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`
. My question is how to get the json response mentioned in the link above. Also exec is not enabled on this task. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by: "i am not able to find anywhere this variable ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4"? That variable is available inside the container running on ECS. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Hi @MarkB this is my first time of trying this, not sure how to access the container running on fargate launch type. Do i need ecs exec for this..?

Comment: Yes you would `ecs exec` in for this. Typically this is for the software running in the container to access the metadata endpoint, not for you to use outside of the container. Why are you needing to access this endpoint?

Comment: I think I got it @MarkB. So the spring boot java app that is running inside container can easily access this variable  using maybe system.getenv and i can also use httpclient to get the json response. Will check this

Comment: Yes that's correct. But again, why do you need this info outside of the container? That same info should be available from the AWS ECS API instead of going through the metadata endpoint.